# Java getMethod() with generic class

Tags: java, android, retrofit, getmethod

i'm trying to get a method from an interface
I read about getMethod() function and as document said

```
public Method getMethod(String name, Class<?>... parameterTypes)
```

is the declaration for java.lang.Class.getMethod() method

i have **no problem** with methods that get **simple types** like

```
Call<ApiR<SelfVM>> Get(String value);
```

here passing **String.class** works correctly

---

but when a method **need generic class** i became a little confuse about that and

### here is my question

that what should i pass instead of **parameterTypes** in methods like

```
Call<ApiR<SelfVM>> Set(SendR<SelfVM> vm);
```

---

**SendR** and **SelfVM** classes

```
public class SendR <T> {

    private T value;
    private String token;

    public SendR(T value, String token) {
        this.value = value;
        this.token = token;
    }

}
```

---

```
public class SelfVM {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String lastName;

    public SelfVM(String id, String name, String lastName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

}
```

---

and here is s.th i've tried

*CalculateResult function:*

```
protected static void CalculateResult(final Object interfaceObject,
                                      final String methodName,
                                      final Class<?> viewModelClassType,
                                      final Object viewModelObject,
                                      final CalculateResultCallBack callBack) {
    Method method;
    Call<ApiR> result = null;
    method = interfaceObject
          .getClass()
          .getMethod(methodName, viewModelClassType);
    result = (Call<ApiR>) method.invoke(interfaceObject, viewModelObject);
}
```

*and here is where i call CalculateResult function*

```
static SelfInterface apiService =
        ApiSetting.getClient().create(SelfInterface.class);

public static void get(CalculateResultCallBack<SelfVM> callBack) {
    CalculateResult(apiService, "Get", null,
            null, callBack);
}

public static void set(SendR<SelfVM> vm, CalculateResultCallBack<SelfVM> callBack) {
    CalculateResult(apiService, "Set", SendR.class, vm, callBack);
}
```

*ApiSetting.getClient()*

```
public class ApiSetting {
    public static Retrofit getClient() {
            if (retrofit == null) {
                retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .client(okHttpClient)
                        .build();
            }
            return retrofit;
        }
}
```

*get and set methods*

```
@GET("json.txt")
Call<ApiR<SelfVM>> Get();


@PUT("json.txt")
Call<ApiR<SelfVM>> Set(SendR<SelfVM> vm);
```

Comment: Just `SendR.class`

Comment: Reflection is not type safe anyway in Java. There is no point in putting so much energy on this. You'll have to manually cast the resulting type.

Comment: @shmosel then what's your idea for passing **args** in `invoke(Object receiver, Object... args)` ???   i pass `SendR<SelfVM> object` but it goes to **InvocationTargetException**

Comment: during compile time, `SendR<SelfVM>` is transformed to `SendR<Object>`.. so you cant get a class of a generic type. just `SendR.class`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @user2914191 thanks but as i said in comment, i tested `SendR.class` but it goes to **InvocationTargetException** i added the codes that i've tried , what's your idea about passing `vm` in this code `CalculateResult(apiService, "Set", SendR.class, vm, callBack);`

Comment: your `SelfInterface` is created by `ApiSetting.getClient().create(SelfInterface.class);`. you dont show how that object is created, and thus its impossible to answer

Comment: @user2914191 many thanks for your answers ... i just add `ApiSetting` class and `getClient()` function ... but i think that it doesn't have any relation to question

Comment: add full stack trace of the error with the `InvocationTargetException`